# Is there a way to open Microsoft Map on Windows 10 from browser javascript

Tags: javascript, navigation

I'm working on an app which will contain an address.  The user can click or tap on the address, on an android device, the following web page code runs which opens Google Navigation with the destination address and ready for turn by turn.

Here is the code:
 window.open("google.navigation:q=lat,lon", '_system');

I'm trying to do this on for other devices such as a window 10 surface with the Here Windows Maps installed?

I run the code above on a Surface and you get a prompt that says you need to find a app in the store to open google.navigation so I'm thinking it could possibly be done.

Does anybody know if this is possible?  Next will trying to figure out how to open up navigation on an Apple tablet or phone if anybody has any pointers for that platform.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After posting this, I stumbled across a link that showed some [launch commands](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/how-open-windows-10-apps-using-shell-commands).

The below is working.  A user is prompted to open an application which is understandable but it does open Windows maps to navigation and calculates the route.

Still looking for a way to do this on idevices.

```
function GetMobileOperatingSystem() {
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;


if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {

    return 'iOS';

}
else if (userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {

    return 'Android';
}
else if(userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i))
{
    return 'Windows Phone';
}
else if (userAgent.match(/Windows NT/i) && userAgent.match(/Tablet PC/i)) {
    return 'Windows Tablet';
}
else if (userAgent.match(/Windows NT/i)) {
    return 'Windows Desktop';
}
else {
    return 'unknown';
}
}

function OpenNavigation(lat, lon) {
    // If Android device, open coordinates for google navigation
    if (GetMobileOperatingSystem() === 'Android') {
        // window.open("google.navigation:q=35.208707,-80.830739", '_system');
        window.open("google.navigation:q=lat,lon", '_system');
    }
    else if(GetMobileOperatingSystem().match(/Windows/i))
    {
        // window.open("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + lat + "," + lon);
        window.open("ms-drive-to:?destination.latitude=" + lat + "&destination.longitude=" + lon);
    }


}
```